# Check variable of Time within a timeframe

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

Is there a way to check and see if a time is between a time duration in Crystal Report? Our application has a field, let’s say, called StopTime but stored in integer format. It has the value of 0 at midnight, 60 at 1 am, … , 12x60= 720 at noon.

There is a need for me to create an input parameter with type Time which allows a range value so that user could select to view records within a certain time in the day.

[image]

My question is how do I check the value of the field again the input parameter in the record selection formula? I have tried

```
cast({StopTime}/60 as time) in {?TimeDuration}
```

but I got the error “There is an error in the formula. Do you want to save it anyway?”

I have also tried

```
{StopTime}/60 in {?TimeDuration}
```

and still got the error.

The only way to get around this error is declaring the parameter TimeDuration as Number that accepts a range. However, if possible, it is better to use the type of Time as I can foresee user issues with Number range when a time range is actually needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field {StopTime} is a number representing a number of minutes, and so must be cast to a time.  In Crystal Syntax this is achieved using the CTime function which takes a parameter of a number in days.  Therefore you must divide the number of minutes by 1440 to get it in to days. The following will do what you need.

```
ctime({StopTime}/1440) in {?TimeDuration}
```